# Help identifying a microprocessor?

Tags: microprocessor, eeprom

I've recently started trying to reverse engineer my old car's ECU (2001 Holden Jackaroo/Isuzu Trooper with a 3.0L diesel 4jx1 engine),  purely as a learning experience. I've managed to identify and dump the contents of the EEPROM on the board ([AM29F200BT](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/100/spansion%20inc._am29f200b_eol_21526d7-1161348.pdf)). You may have to bear with me as my knowledge in this department is very basic.

As I understand it, it will make it easier to reverse engineer the program stored on the EEPROM, if I manage to identify the main microprocessor and the code it uses. However I'm having trouble identifying the main microprocessor on the board. I've tried googling the numbers with no success.

Has anyone seen one of these before or can anyone point me in the right direction of working out which family of microprocessors it belongs to?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I appreciate that you're a beginner. Reverse-engineering ECUs is a specialist area, and while I'm not an expert, I've got some concerns about some details & assumptions in the question. (a) You mention "eprom" several times. Are you *sure* it's an EPROM, and not an **E**EPROM? Since you've read it already, please give its part number. (b) Why do you believe that the "eprom" contains the program code for this ECU? || Although you've just asked an identification type of question, I'm not sure that "microprocessor" (probably actually MCU) identification is going to help you, realistically :-(

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any advice i can get is greatly appreciated. I do believe it is indeed an eeprom(though its been a few weeks since i looked at it.) I've updated the original post to include the eeprom ID number.

Comment: It would be very helpful to disclose your "old car" make and model, as well as year of ECU production (from some IC labels for example). There might be car enthusiast groups who might have full information about your ECU

Comment: I've included the car make and model and engine number, though i cannot find any information on when exactly the ECU was manufactured.

Comment: Saw a post recently of a guy reviewing the new Tesla, right down to identifying chipsets. As you have found, automakers are not opensource orientated.

I've got a feeling even if you stripped the epoxy coating, chip numbers will not be legible/visible. good luck.

Comment: I have seen custom MCU specially ordered for ECUs. Numbers won't make any sense at all and the data sheets I doubt that will be available easily..

Comment: A picture of the entire ECU boad might help to identify/match it to already hacked Isuzu ECUs.

Comment: +1 for posting an "in focus" pictures ..... usually the printing is more visible if you reflect a light colored background

Answer (score 2):

It is very likely a Nippon Denso re-branded Motorola-mastered MCU MC68HC16 series, in distinctive 132-pin PQFP package, possibly MC68HC916R1, but might have custom modifications.

See [how-to-hack-the-ecu-of-isuzu-trucks-from-japan](http://ecuhacking.activeboard.com/t51948931/how-to-hack-the-ecu-of-isuzu-trucks-from-japan/),  [Link2](http://ecuhacking.activeboard.com/t9325284/cpu/?page=1#comment-9342054).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful responses. I had actually stumbled across those links before, though with my limited knowledge couldnt put 2 and 2 together. Much appreciated.

Comment: So after a bit more research and tinkering. The mcu seems to be a closer match to the mc6833x family.